# Why must I cast in Kotlin but not Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

**Question**: Why must I cast the type in Kotlin but not in Java?

I have a java method:

```
processAction(Observable<Action> actions)
```

I call it in test (Java):

```
when(myMock.processAction(any(Observable.class))).thenAnswer(...)
```

I call it in test (Kotlin):

```
when(myMock.processAction(any(Observable::class.java) as Observable<Action>).thenAnswer(...)
```

[Repo Here](https://github.com/HIFILEO/ReactiveArchitectureKotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/reactivearchitecture/nowplaying/interactor/NowPlayingInteractor.java#L165)

Comment: Could you please explain what these methods do, as in parameters, annotations, and return types? This is most likely related to nullability of the parameters.

Comment: I pasted a link to the repo. I didn't want to answer your question and muddy the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, your expressions have the following types:

- `Observable.class` -> `Class<Observable>`
- `any(Observable.class)` -> `Observable`

Likewise in Kotlin:

- `Observable::class.java` -> `Class<Observable<*>>`
- `any(Observable::class.java)` -> `Observable<*>`

In Java, `Observable` is a raw type; you should expect your compiler/IDE to highlight a warning when you implicitly convert to `Observable<Action>`.  For backward-compatibility with a pre-generics world, this doesn't fail to compile.

Kotlin tries to be smarter about how it handles generics, plus the backward-compatibility thing doesn't apply.  So it forces you to be explicit about your intent here.

---

*On a tangent, if you're using Mockito in Kotlin I highly recommend the [Mockito-Kotlin bindings](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin), as they make this substantially less verbose (it would just be `any()` in this case).*

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new every day. In regards to the Mockito-Kotlin, it looks like it hasn't been updated in a while...was hesitant to use it.